ESP32 webserver with a loaded page fails to update data in elements after sending an Json file, the Json data is printed instead of the loaded page
I've an ESP32 with a web server, in the page where I show the sensor readings and the state of the system, right now the readings are showing themselves well, the problem comes when I want to show the state of the system.
Right now I'm testing the behavior only with the /encender page, The state of the system is sent in a Json file to only update the elements that contains the system state but instead of update those html elements, the page dessapears and the web explorer shows me an error of empty response.
here follows my actual code related to my problem:
Code related to the /encender page (an  element) in backend.cpp:
server.on("/encender", HTTP_GET,[](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    digitalWrite(ledPinSistemaApagado,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPinSistemaEncendido,HIGH);
    if(ultimaPaginaCargada == "/encender");
    {
      Serial.println("No se envía la página /encender, solo se actualizará el estado del sistema.");
      request->send(200);
      return;
    }
    ultimaPaginaCargada = "/encender";
    cuentaAcceso = true;
    request->send(SPIFFS,"/index.html", String(), false, Procesador);
  });

the code in backend.cpp related to the update of the state of the function is like follows
server.on("/data-estado", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    if(!request->authenticate(usuarioHTTP, claveHTTP) && !cuentaAcceso) {
        return request->requestAuthentication("Ingreso al Sistema");
    };
    Serial.println("Enviando la data de estado.");
    sistemaEstado["estado-sistema"] = ledEstado;
    sistemaEstado["modo-sistema"] = modoSistema;
    String json = "";
    serializeJsonPretty(sistemaEstado, json);
    Serial.println(json);
    ultimaPaginaCargada = "/data-estado";
    cuentaAcceso = true;
    request->send(200, "application/json", json);
    json = String();
    Serial.println("Enviada la data de estado.");
});

right now the above piece of code, if the variable ùltimaPaginaCargada is "/encender", it means that the page /encender was previously loaded, so it only sends "200" to the web explorer, on the contrary the "/encender" wasn't previously loaded and that page is sent.
Following is the code on my app.js:
function Actualiza_Estado() {
    console.log("Entrando a Actualiza_Estado().");
    var xxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
        console.log("Analizando los componentes reibidos en Actualiza_Estado()");
        var estadoWeb = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(estadoWeb);
        var estadoEnc = document.getElementById("estado-sistema");
        estadoEnc.innerHTML = "<p>Estado Sistema: " + "<strong>" + `${estadoWeb.estado-sistema}` + "</strong>";
        var modoEnc = document.getElementById("modo-sistema");
        modoEnc.innerHTML = "<p>Modo Sistema: " + "<strong>" + `${modoEnc.modo-sistema}` + "</strong>";
        console.log("Enviados los componentes a actualizar a la pantalla");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Contenido no cargado en Actualiza_Estado()");
        
    }
    xxhr.open("HTTP_GET", "/data-estado", true);
    xxhr.send();
    console.log("Solicitada la actualización del estado del sistema");
};

// Funciones para mostrar el nivel del tanque en la página de visualización.

function Lee_Nivel_Tanque() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
        {
            var volTanqueWeb = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            console.log(volTanqueWeb);
            var volActualWeb = document.getElementById("mask01");
            volActualWeb.innerHTML = volTanqueWeb.colAgua.toFixed(2);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Contenido no cargado en Lee_Nivel_Tanque()");
        }
    };
    xhr.open("HTTP_GET", "/data-tanque", true);
    xhr.send();
    console.log("Solicitada actualización del tanque.");
};

// Funciones para enviar la hora y la fecha a la ventana

function Fecha_Hora() {
    let hoyFecha = new Date();
    let hoyHora = hoyFecha.toLocaleTimeString();
    let dia = hoyFecha.getDate();
    let mes = hoyFecha.getMonth() + 1;
    let anio = hoyFecha.getFullYear();
    let diaSemana = hoyFecha.getDay();
    dia = ('0' + dia).slice(-2);
    mes = ('0' + mes).slice(-2);
    let semana = ['DOMINGO', 'LUNES', 'MARTES', 'MIÉRCOLES', 'JUEVES', 'VIERNES', 'SÁBADO'];
    let muestraSemana = semana[diaSemana];
    let fechaCompleta = `${muestraSemana}-${dia}-${mes}-${anio}`;
    document.getElementById("la-fecha").innerHTML = fechaCompleta;
    document.getElementById("la-hora").innerHTML = hoyHora;
    console.log(fechaCompleta + '->' + hoyHora);
};

window.onload = function() {
    let intervaloVolumen;
    let intervaloFecha;
    intervaloFecha = setInterval(Fecha_Hora, 1000);
    if((window.location.pathname === "/index") ||
        (window.location.pathname === "/apagar") ||
        (window.location.pathname === "/encender") ||
        (window.location.pathname === "/auto") ||
        (window.location.pathname === "/manual"))
    {
        //Actualiza_Estado();
        intervaloVolumen = setInterval(Lee_Nivel_Tanque, 20000);
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(intervaloVolumen);
        intervaloVolumen = null;
    }
}

var datoEstado = document.getElementsByClassName("boton-control");
datoEstado.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Actualiza_Estado();
});

above the functions that I think matters are Àctualiza_Estado() and the var datoEstado, datoEstado is bassically a listener that when I make click at any of the buttons made with <a> elements it calls Àctualiza_Estado() to request the Json file with the state of the system.
On the window.onload() function if any of the buttons or the proncipal page are loaded then it defines an interval to update the parameter to read from the sensor and every 20 seconds it requests a Json file whith that data (this works excelent).
is that in the function server.on() related to /encender page, I make the program to send a 200 response to the request to make the ESP32 code to send only the Json file by calling the Actualiza_Estado() function with requests /data-estado but like I said the web explorer seems to have an empty response.
I've made a variation in the function server.on() related to /encender page in backend.cpp to force the sending of the Json file directly from there like follows
server.on("/encender", HTTP_GET,[](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    digitalWrite(ledPinSistemaApagado,LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledPinSistemaEncendido,HIGH);
    if(ultimaPaginaCargada == "/encender");
    {
    Serial.println("Enviando la data de estado.");
    sistemaEstado["estado-sistema"] = ledEstado;
    sistemaEstado["modo-sistema"] = modoSistema;
    String json = "";
    serializeJsonPretty(sistemaEstado, json);
    Serial.println(json);
    ultimaPaginaCargada = "/data-estado";
    cuentaAcceso = true;
    request->send(200, "application/json", json);
    json = String();
    }
    ultimaPaginaCargada = "/encender";
    cuentaAcceso = true;
    request->send(SPIFFS,"/index.html", String(), false, Procesador);
});

in the above case the web explorer receives the Json file and displays de data but in an empty black page and shows the formatted Json file.
I don't know whats happening because the method of Json file works very well when using it for the sensor reading with Lee_Nivel_Tanque().
What can I do to solve the problem?

estadoWeb.estado-sistema needs to be estadoWeb["estado-sistema"]

The issue you're experiencing is likely due to the handling of the request->send(200); in the /encender endpoint. Have you already solved the problem?

@tepalia yes, I could solve the problem based on all your advices

I didn't go through all the question. Just looking at the code there are
quite a few issues that deserve to be addressed.
In the back-end for /encender, you have
    if(ultimaPaginaCargada == "/encender");
    {
    // ...

Notice the semicolon right after the condition. In C++, a bare semicolon
is an empty statement (a no-op). Here, this empty statement is the body
of the if statement. The braced block that follows is executed
unconditionally. This is most likely not what you mean.
        request->send(200);

Do not send an empty 200 response. If you want to tell the client “your
request has been processed successfully, but I have nothing to send to
you”, you should send a 204 No Content response.
    ultimaPaginaCargada = "/encender";

A Web API is supposed to be stateless. If you need to remember the last
page loaded, your whole protocol is most likely flawed.
On the JavaScript function Actualiza_Estado():
    var xxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

The second line does not belong here: it should be within a
onreadystatechange handler. See how Lee_Nivel_Tanque() is written.

Edit: A few more remarks.
if(ultimaPaginaCargada == "/encender");

I previously wrote “If you need to remember the last page loaded, your
whole protocol is most likely flawed.” You may have misunderstood this
point. The problem is not that the server remembers which page was
loaded last. The problem is that its behavior depends on this
information. The server response should not depend on what page was
loaded last.
request->send(SPIFFS, "/index.html", String(), false, Procesador);

This looks fishy. I am not sure I fully understand your approach but,
from the little you show, it looks to me like you are building a
Web-based user interface for some device in the form of a
single-page application. In this approach, you have:

A single URL (typically the root: /) that delivers the user
interface in the form of a static HTML document, possibly with
embedded JavaScript.
Zero or more URLs that deliver static assets required by that
document: JavaScript, images, fonts…
One or more endpoints that let you interact with the device by either
retrieving JSON-formatted dynamic data (GET endpoints) or changing
the device's state (POST endpoints).

In this approach, the only instance where you may serve an HTML document
is in response to a GET / request. A dynamic data endpoint should
never deliver index.html.
xxhr.open("HTTP_GET", "/data-estado", true);

The HTTP method should be written "GET", not "HTTP_GET".

Hi @Edgar Bonet, thanks for the corrections, I didn't note that I  left that semicolon there, and thank you for the advice about the stateless api, I'll make some modifications and I'll let you know

and I must note that for Actualiza_Estado() I don't want an time interval, in addition, I know you are reffering to the the remembering of the last loaded page in my backend.cpp, at that time I didn't need to remember the pages, I just wanted to store the last loaded page. Following, the Actualiza_Estado() function is meant to show in the web page the state of the hardware part of my project, if is ON or OFF, etc.

and thank you for the 204 response advice
